# grep within an if statement

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am writing a function that prompts for the name of a file and then make sure the input starts with a alpha char, if it doesn't it will re prompt the user for a name until the criteria is met. It also gives an additional message if the user inputs a path(a path is anything with a '/' for the purpose of this assignment). That is where I am getting an issue...

here is my code...

```
#1) make a getname function that will prompt for filename
function getname(){
trap control_c SIGINT
local fname=$1;

#if there is no input prompt user for file name
if [ ! $1 ]; then
        read -p "Enter a file name: " fname;
fi;

#until grep is given a valid file name
until ( grep -E '^[a-zA-Z_]\w+$' <<< "$fname" > /dev/null 2>&1); do





        #this is were the error is
        if echo "$fname" | grep -E '/';





         then                           #this tests if fname is a file directory
        echo "Paths are not a legal file name.";
        fi;
        read -p "Enter a legal file name: " fname;
done
echo "$fname"
}
```

The if statement within the until loop will not prompt the user that paths are not valid input under any circumstances and also produces no errors. How would I properly implement a grep in an if statement?

Comment: The way you test whether $fname is a directory or not is simply wrong. You could simply use `if [ -d "$fname" ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does work for me at Fedora 26 using `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`. The function keeps asking if path is given. See the output.

```
[@host testing]$ getname
Enter a file name: ab/sav
ab/sav
Paths are not a legal file name.
Enter a legal file name: abc                    
abc
[@host testing]$
```

However, I found two little issues. First, it prints the path and then it asks again for input. This can be solved by using switch `grep -q` (q for quiet) in the `if` statement (also works for the `until`, then the output redirection is no longer needed). Second, a single character is always invalid in the `until` loop. This can be solved by changing `\w+` in regex for `\w*`.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` in until statement is very bulky, you can simplify it.

I can suggest this method:

```
until [ ! -z "$fname" ]; do
        read -p "Enter a legal file name: " fname
        grep -E '^[a-zA-Z_]\w+$' <<< "$fname" > /dev/null 2>&1

        #check exit code
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "Paths are not a legal file name."
                fname=""
        fi
done
```

Append any different conditions inside until loop if you need.

If you want to handle messages for users then you can use this trick without several `read` command appearances:

```
fname=""
message_for_user="Enter a file name: "

until [ ! -z "$fname" ]; do
        read -p "$message_for_user" fname
        grep -E '^[a-zA-Z_]\w+$' <<< "$fname" > /dev/null 2>&1

        #check exit code
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "Paths are not a legal file name."
                fname=""
                message_for_user="Enter a legal file name: "
        fi
done
```

Output will be:

```
Enter a file name: 1laha
Paths are not a legal file name.
Enter a legal file name:
```

Note that the first and the third lines are different

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp in an `if` statement directly:

```
if [[ $name  =~ ^[a-zA-Z] ]]
```

or:

```
if [[ $name  =~ ^[:alpha:] ]]
```